# Best way of determining how unique an inspector's ratings are compared to the average inspector

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, ranking, measurement, rating

Noob question.

I have a full population of every inspector rating for all items being rated. Each inspector has inspected a subset of the items and given them a rating, but different inspectors have inspected a different number of items.

My goal is to measure how different the ratings are that a given inspector gives compared to the population of inspectors (i.e. who is the most out of line compared to the average inspector). I could do something like, for every inspector, compute the mean squared error for all the ratings an inspector has given (error as the distance between the average rating for an item and the rating the inspector has given), but the item rating distributions might have different stddevs. This also seems like it would have weird behavior for inspectors that have only inspected a small number of items.

Are there any statistical measures that would be appropriate here?

Comment: Are all of the items different? If not I would calculate an average rating for each of the items and would rate inspectors based on MSE prediction of the average score

Comment: I was a bit worried that MSE prediction to average score wouldn't quite capture that (1) the ratings for each item can have different variances (seems like it might be worth penalizing further away predictions on items with small variance) and (2) different inspectors will have rated a different number of items. Maybe this second thing isn't that important, but I think we can have higher confidence in inspectors being bad/good if they've rated a lot of items.

Comment: You can try scaling your scores, so that variances would be the same